# Position modal to the left (Bootstrap 4 & MVC 5) not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using a modal window to display an iframe. The page displayed in the iframe i very wide, so i've set the necessary width on it. The modal is however fixed to the middle of the screen, so the modal window goes past the right side of the screen, which means that I cannot view the whole iframe. Here's is where my problem arises, in that I want to place the modal on the left side of the screen.

I have tried using the solutions from multiple posts on this site and other forums. I even tried to use this example:

```
* MODAL AS LEFT/RIGHT SIDEBAR
* Add "left" or "right" in modal parent div, after class="modal".
* Get free snippets on bootpen.com
*******************************/
    .modal.left .modal-dialog,
    .modal.right .modal-dialog {
        position: fixed;
        margin: auto;
        width: 320px;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
             -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    }

    .modal.left .modal-content,
    .modal.right .modal-content {
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    .modal.left .modal-body,
    .modal.right .modal-body {
        padding: 15px 15px 80px;
    }

/*Left*/
    .modal.left.fade .modal-dialog{
        left: -320px;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
           -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
             -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
                transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    
    .modal.left.fade.in .modal-dialog{
        left: 0;
    }
        
/*Right*/
    .modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
        right: -320px;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
           -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
             -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
                transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    
    .modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog {
        right: 0;
    }

/* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
    .modal-content {
        border-radius: 0;
        border: none;
    }

    .modal-header {
        border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
    }

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
    background-color: #78909C;
}

.demo {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.btn-demo {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-demo:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.demo-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #212121;
    text-align: center;
}

.demo-footer > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
} 

https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa
```

from a post on here. The example works on codepen, but when I copy paste it into my code, it opens the modal in the middle of the screen. I have tried setting margin-left to 0 on all modal related css blocks as well as removing all modal related css blocks except from the ones from the example.

My guess is that something, somewhere, is overriding the modal positioning, but the fact that I have removed all modal related css code, except from the example and it still does not work, confuses me. I've also tried to remove and css code for the pages in general (from the Site.css file). I'm using Bootstrap 4 (v4.5) and I only have bootstrap stylesheets except for the regular Site.css sheet.

Any ideas on where to begin to find the culprit?

**UPDATE**
Here's the html code for my page, maybe there's something here that interferes:

```
@using System.Configuration
@model ProdSplitScreen.Models.PressModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProdSplitScreen";
    var prefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PREFIX"];
    var prodscreen = $"http://{prefix}privatesite.network.net/{Model.Press}/{Model.Language}";
}


@if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{<p>it works!: <a href="@Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()">@Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()</a></p>}

<iframe style="width:50%" src="@prodscreen"></iframe>
<iframe style="width:50%" src="@(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SCANPORTAL"])"></iframe>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-target="#MyModal" data-toggle="modal">Modal Button</button>
<div class="modal left fade" id="MyModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:1400px;height:1000px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Demo</h4>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src="@(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SCANPORTAL"])"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />

@* CODEPEN EXAMPLE *@
<div class="container demo">


    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Left Sidebar Modal
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal left fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Left Sidebar</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div><!-- modal-content -->
        </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- modal -->


</div><!-- container -->

<footer class="demo-footer">
    <a href="http://www.bootpen.com" target="_blank">Get more code snippets</a>
</footer>
```

I've added a screenshot of the modal positioning itself at the top middle.
[image: screenshot of the left modal appearing in the top middle]

Comment: Can you please share the html you have tried as well? It would be great if you could make a snippet of your problem also and include it in your question

Comment: You can just use the codepen example: https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa
neither this nor my own html works. I have updated the post with the rest of the html in my page. There's 3 scripts imported, they are javascripts and I need them to open the modals, but maybe they interfere somehow?

Comment: The code snippet you are using is for Bootstrap 3 and you are using Bootstrap 4. Here is a fiddle of it using your HTML and the styles, but with Bootstrap 3 not 4: https://jsfiddle.net/wa1z63t8/ In bootstrap 4 they rewrote the modal component in flexbox ([ref](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#modal))

Comment: So I should just use flexbox instead @zgood? I'm confused, because w3schools indicates that Modal should work fine with bootstrap 4 ([ref](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp)) but the example from them does not work either. (for me atleast)

Comment: I just tested it with a new app and it works in bootstrap 3, but not in 4, just as you said. Do you have any recommendations to an alternative? I just need to show a large iframe in a popup window.

Answer (score 0):

As user @zgood explained in a comment, the problem was that my code was not compatible with bootstrap 4 (it was meant for bootstrap 3). Rather than downgrading my application, I used examples and js/css files from this site: [MDBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/modals/basic/), which works perfectly with bootstrap 4.5. I can recommend using their examples and files if you want to use modals with Bootstrap 4.

My working code is just their "Side Modal" example where I use the top-left position.